# Log exception and parameters

Tags: java, slf4j

I use sl4j-api 1.7.2 with slf4j-log4j12.

I would like to log something like this:

> 22:52:27,345 WARN [class] Failed to load user 1 - Reason : 
>   javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity
>   found for query at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] 
>   ... fullstackTrace

So I tried

```
try {
            //...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Failed to load User {} - Reason : {}", userId, e);
        }
```

Or

```
try {
               // ...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warn("Failed to load User {} - Reason : ", userId, e);
            }
```

But none of this two solutions work

The first try give :

> Failed to load User 4 - Reason : javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query

The second :

```
Failed to load User 4 - Reason :
```

Is it possible to made it ?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not good to log implementation details

Comment: I am using slf4j with logback (the default implementation) and it prints out the first 8 lines of the stack trace for both of your examples, and also without the "{}" replacement at all. Maybe it is your configuration of log4j, or the print format, or log4j itself (although I doubt it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [Logger API](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html) and the [SL4J FAQ](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#paramException). You are probably using a SL4J version prior to 1.6.0 in which `e` will be interpreted as a simple object (i.e., SL4J will call `e.toString()`) if you have a parameter placeholder or ignored if you don't.

As for why it is using a version different than 1.7.2, a previous version is probably included in your Application Server Classpath and getting loaded before you even start your application.

You can either try to fix the Classloading problem or workaround the old version behavior.

If you choose the latter path, from the overloaded versions you need either the `warn(String msg, Throwable t))` version that auto expands the stacktrace:

```
logger.warn("Failed to load User " + userId + " - Reason",  e);
```

Or the `warn(String format, Object arg1, Object arg2)` one with code that expands the stacktrace for you.

```
if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
   StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
   e.printStackTrace(pw);
   String expanded = sw.toString(); // stack trace as a string
   logger.warn("Failed to load User {} - Reason : {}", userId, expanded);
}
```

Comment: Wrong version in classpath bad jboss :(

Answer (score 0):

This might be not obvious, but with Slf4J it's possible to attach exception to the `log event` if exception passed as a last argument.

Example:

```
logger.error("Parameterized msg {} {} {}", 1, 2, 3, exception)
```

Output (JSON Appender in my case):

```
{"message":"Parameterized msg 1 2 3","logger_name":"com.may.Main$","stack_trace":"java.lang.Exception: My Exception\n\tat com.may.Main$.main(Main.scala:34)\n\tat com.may.Main.main(Main.scala)\n","application":"app1","environment":"ENV"}
```

Docs:

https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#paramException